# Dependencias nulas con patron singleton

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Tengo una clase a la cual la llamo desde otra clase:

```
public class caller {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Calle.getInstance().run();
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Swagger2SpringBoot.class }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("api")
public final class Calle extends AbstractTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserApi userApi;

    private static final Calle INSTANCE = new Calle();

    public static Calle getInstance() {
        return Calle.INSTANCE;
    }

    private Calle() {
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        final User usr1 = this.createUser(this.userApi);
    }
}
```

---

```
 MAIN

@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
         "es.comp.api",
         "es.comp.api.controller",
         "es.comp.api.configuration"
    }
```

La clase UserApi esta añadidida en el main ("es.comp.api.controller",)

Al parecer y por lo que pude leer. Cuando se llama a una clase de manera singleton. Spring no carga las dependencias que se cargan con la etiqueta @Autowired. Entonces al hacer el **this.createUser(this.userApi)** Me da un NullPointerException.

Como podria solventar esta falla?
Un saludo

Comment: La clase UserApi está creada en el mismo paquete que la clase Calle? Lo que te está pasando es que spring no tiene la clase UserApi en el application context por ello no te la puede inyectar como dependencia, hay que ver por qué la clase UserApi no ha sido creada por spring.

Comment: Se encuentra en otro paquete de otro nivel. Lo que no termino de entender es que estando en otro paquete al mismo nivel si me funcionaba. Y ahora que he tenido que meter esto haciendo instancias a la propia clase de manera singleton. No es capaz Spring de cargarlo

Comment: Probaste en dejar Calle sin el singleton, a ver si así te inyecta la dependencia?

Comment: Acabo de probar y aun asi no me lo carga. Al parecer, como decias, no me carga la dependencia. Que podria estar haciendo mal?? No se hacia con la etiqueta @ComponentScan en el main?

Comment: Vale, Estoy llamando desde la clase Caller a una clase que not enia singleton y que si le daba boton derecho y ejecutaba directamente. Me funcionaba todo perfectamente. Ahora desde el Caller he llamado a esa misma clase que funcionaba y estoy teniendo el mismo error. Null a todas las dependencias. Lo estoy haciendo con null puede que este machancando el contexto

Comment: me parece que tu metodo anotado con  @test debe estar en la clase Calle no en otra clase aparte por lo que he estado leyendo en la documentación, fijate los ejemplos que coloca: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: El caso es que tenia una clase que funcionaba. He copiado su contenido y lo he metido en la clase Calle. Y lo llamaba desde el Caller. Y falla. He cambiado la llamada y en vez de llamar a Calle(Singleton) he llamado a la que funcionaba previamente. Y me da null

Comment: He probado y no. Seguire mirando aver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas Spring para generar instancias de cualquier objeto, Spring se encarga de analizar su clase y encontrar dependencias.
Si creas una instancia de cualquier clase llamando *manualmente* a su constructor, esa instancia no es conocida por Spring y por tanto no va a inyectarle nada.
La solución más sencilla sería seguir usando Spring para obtener la instancia, algo como:

```
@Bean
public class caller {

    @Autowired private Calle c;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.c.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracais por la ayuda